# Getting AJAX to load to a div from Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

So it's just a div with `id="calendar"` that is suppose to load from a controller method automatically. There is a reason for this. I need to manipulate it on the backend for various reasons, but I cannot get it to even load up on the screen with the test. I'm fairly new to using AJAX.

This is my HTML/AJAX:

```
    <body>
<x-dispatch.header/>

<x-dispatch.nav/>

<div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row">

    {{-- <x-callCenter.ccSidebar/> --}}


     <div class="main-content flex-1 bg-gray-100 mt-12 md:mt-2 pb-24 md:pb-5">

        <div class="bg-gray-800 pt-3">
            <div class="rounded-tl-3xl bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-900 to-gray-800 p-4 shadow text-2xl text-white">
                <h3 class="font-bold pl-2">Calendar</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

    
<div class = "pl-8"id="container">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="monthDisplay"></div>
    <div>
      <button id="backButton">Back</button>
      <button id="nextButton">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="weekdays">
    <div>Sunday</div>
    <div>Monday</div>
    <div>Tuesday</div>
    <div>Wednesday</div>
    <div>Thursday</div>
    <div>Friday</div>
    <div>Saturday</div>
  </div>

  <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>

<div id="newEventModal">
  <h2>Add New Service Time Slot</h2>

    <form action = "{{ route('addEvent') }}" method = "POST">
    @csrf
    <input id="eventTitleInput" placeholder="Service Type and Time Slot" />
    <input type="text" name="title" id="">
    <input type="text" name="time_slot" id="">
    <input class = "hidden" name="event_date" id="event_date" value="">
    <button id="saveButton" type = "submit">Save</button>
    <button id="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
  </form>
  </div>

<div id="deleteEventModal">
  <h2>Event</h2>

  <p id="eventText"></p>

  <button id="deleteButton">Delete</button>
  <button id="closeButton">Close</button>
</div>

<div id="modalBackDrop"></div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function()
    {

              $.ajax
              ({
                  url:"calendar",
                  type:"GET",
                  
                  
                  success:function(data)
                  {
                      $('#calendar').html(data);
                  }
              });
          }
      
    });
</script>
```

And this is my controller method:

```
    public function getEvents(){
    $events = Event::all();
    
    $nav = 0;

    $output = '
    
    <p>hi</p>
    
    ';

    return $output;
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/callCenter/calendar','App\Http\Controllers\CallCenter\EventsController@getEvents');
```

Comment: Do you get any error message in your DevTools 'Network' panel? What is the HTTP status code you're getting? If that doesn't help, what's the output of `dd($events)`?

Comment: The dd($events) is spitting out the events from the database fine. Its displaying just the output from the controller to the entire page and not just inside the div with id="calendar".

Comment: Could you please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68470881/edit) the surrounding code to your div in your question?

Comment: Sure there is the surrounding html.

Comment: Looks okay. I can't see anything that would cause replacing the whole page's content with the AJAX result.

Answer (score 0):

The route definition differs from the API call. So you either

1. Change the route definition

```
Route::get('/calendar','App\Http\Controllers\CallCenter\EventsController@getEvents');
```

2. Change the API call

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            url:"/callCenter/calendar", // if the route is defined in routes/api.php, you need to prefix it with api/
            type:"GET",
            
            
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#calendar').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Good suggestion. It still just displays the output from the controller to the entire page and not just inside the div with id="calendar". The output from the controller method takes the whole screen and its not just in the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
return response()->json($output);
```

I believe this is what you need. Give it a try. JavaScript will automatically parse the json object.
This is my result. And it should work for you too, no page reloaded. Just play around, I've tried without using reponse() and json() helper, but I can not trigger a whole page reload. May be the problem lies in your HTML
[image]